# How can i get ajax call to work on phonegap

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, phonegap

I am trying to do an ajax call. its just not getting any feedback from the server. can someone help look at my code and advice me on how to go about it. i have looked up lots of answers here but cant seem to get it to work

**Jquery Code**

here is the jquery code that performs the ajax call

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadAllProducts').html('Loading Product...<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>').fadeIn(); 
        
             $.ajax({
                    type : 'post',
                    url : 'https://spg.ng/farmtransactpro/api/loadAllProductsOnLoad.php', 
                    //data :  dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success : function(result){
                    $('#loadAllProducts').html(result).fadeIn();    
                    
                    }
                    
                });
                
                
        });
```

**loadAllProductsOnLoad.php**

this is the api content

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    
     echo 'hi...am bringing feedback';
    ?>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.farmtransact" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

    <name>Farmtransact</name>

  <description>
      FarmTransact is an online marketplace which consists of all kinds of agricultural products and agricultural services
  </description>

 <author email="" href="">
        Chike Okoli
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <access origin="https://spg.ng/farmtransactpro/api/" />
    
    
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <access origin="*" />
    
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    
    
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-128-xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
        
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
        
        
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portraite.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash src="splash.png" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="https://spg.ng/farmtransactpro/api/" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: 1) Where is the ajax running? Show us: where you put that script (is it inline - is it included). 2) Did you define a [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) in the main index file?

Comment: I included it from an external file. Where do i define the Content-Security-Policy ? in the .html file where i put the jquery file? kindly help clerify

Comment: See @CBroe answer. Change the api .php file - echo something that is a valid JSON. Like: echo '{ "status": "ok" }'; Then see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is not triggering the `success` handler.

Add an `error` handler, and log the response to console.

You will see it contains `statusText: "parsererror"` - and that is a result of pretending the response was of `Content-Type: application/json`, but then sending data that is not actually valid JSON.

So, solution: Make your PHP script send actual valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you might have a problem regarding: [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)

I built some apps with Cordova, but I'm not very advanced. This might help you though, so give it a try:

-> in your main `index.html` file, add this in the `head` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' https://spg.ng/farmtransactpro/api/">
```

Does that work?

See here a complete guide for [Cordova Content-Security-Policy - docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)

Comment: Tried that but still getting same result